# Where can i locate display driver in android source code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-x86

I want to change display driver resolution setting according to this article

http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/display_drivers.html

But i am not able to locate display driver in kernel and android code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because author is asking for ready-for-use code, without showing any effort.

Comment: That would be platform specific (or even device specific). For some Qualcomm-based devices you might be able to find the drivers [here](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/kernel/msm), and the display HAL [here](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/hardware/qcom/display/). Note that these types of questions really are off-topic for StackOverflow, so you're probably better off asking on some Android development forum, like xda-developers or the cyanogenmod forums.

Comment: Or possibly http://android.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

The information at that link is pretty stale. The [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/index.html) pages are closer to reality.